# #lang plai racket multiplier function

Tags: tree, programming-languages, racket, plai

I am working on a project to get us used to the plai-typed language for use in a programming languages course. I have been stuck on one question that's really bugging me (finished all the rest with no problem). We are to take this datatype definition :

```
(define-type Tree
[leaf (val number?)]
[node (val number?)
(left Tree?)
(right Tree? ) ] )
```

and then "Implement the function 'scaled', which takes a tree and returns a tree that has the same shape,
but with all the values multiplied by the given scale.

Example: (scaled (node -5 (leaf 6) (leaf -7)) 2) should produce (node -10
(leaf 12) (leaf -14))"

So basically I just need to muliply all those values by a given value, in this example, 2.

Here is what I have so far after trying out different ways:

```
(define (scaled [ t Tree?] [n  number?] )  
(type-case Tree t  
[leaf (val) val] 
[node (val left right) ( * val (scaled left) (scaled right)  n  ) ] ) )
```

I based it on previous code that I created for the other parts of the assignment that I got right. The issue is, it multiplies all the numbers and results "succesfully" with the solution of 420 instead of mutlplying each value individually. I know this has to do with my placement of 'n' but I tried so many different ways with no luck. If anyone has any helpful hints/tips/solution it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way to think about the problem is not by going down to lower levels of implementation but up to a level where we can think about what `scaled` is. The issue isn't figuring out where to put `n`. It's figuring out what `scaled` is supposed to do.

Whatever else it does, it needs to return a tree.

```
; DefType F1 : Any -> Tree
(define (f1 x)
  (leaf 42))
```

The next most important thing is it needs to take a tree as input.

```
; DefType F2 : Tree -> Tree
(define (f2 [t Tree?])
  (leaf 42))
```

There's isomorphism between the input and output that must be addressed next. The structure of the output tree needs to match the structure of the input tree.

```
; DefType F3 : Tree -> Tree
(define (f3 [t Tree?])
  t)
```

This gets us what we want but at the expense of quality from a functional programming standpoint because `f3` returns a reference to the input rather than a value derived from the input. The function needs to return a new output value with the same structure as the input value. To duplicate the structure, the function has to return a `node` when passed a `node` and a `leaf` when passed a `leaf`.

```
; DefType F4 : Tree -> Tree
(define (f4 [t Tree?])
  (type-case Tree t
    [leaf (val) (leaf val)]
    [node (val left right)
       (node val (f4 left)(f4 right))]))
```

Now that the types are sorted out, it's time to deal with transforming the input tree into the output tree. That requires moving up a level rather than down. The place to start is by rewriting `f4`.

```
; DefType F5 : Tree -> Tree
(define (f5 [t Tree?])
  (type-case Tree t
    [leaf (val) (leaf (id val))]
    [node (val left right)
      (node (id val) (f5 left)(f5 right))]))
```

Important, but not very interesting. Replacing `id` with arbitrary functions seems like more fun. So much fun that it's probably worth adding a second argument.

```
; DefType N2N : Number -> Number
; DefType F6 : Tree (Number -> Number) -> Tree
(define (f6 [t Tree?] [n2n N2N?])
  (type-case Tree t
    [leaf (val) (leaf (n2n val))]
    [node (val left right)
      (node (n2n val) (f6 left) (f6 right))]))
```

The function `scaled`:

```
; DefType Scaled : Tree Number -> Tree
(let ((f lambda(x y)(* x y)))
  (define (scaled [t Tree?][n Number?])
    (type-case Tree t
      [leaf (val)(leaf (f n val))]
      [node (val left right)
        (node (f n val) (scaled left)(scaled right))])))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it @benrudgers, it really did help me understand it better! The only thing is, when I run it on racket it gives me an error for the "(let ((f lambda(x y)(* x y)))" line. It says :  "let: bad syntax (not an identifier and expression for a binding) in: (n lambda (x y) (* x y))"

Comment: @CS_Student Writing it out helped me understand and your question prompted me to think about it. So you're welcome and thanks. I put the let outside because it flowed clearly from taking a function as argument to currying that function and just passing a number as argument. The let could be structured other ways to deal with the syntactic requirements of PLAI or another Scheme implementation. `(lambda(x y)(* x y))` just needs to be within an accessible lexical scope.